# Cant load content in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i have a function in webpage with this code :

```
enter code here function LoadGrid() { 
  var gridder = $('#as_gridder'); 
  var UrlToPass = "action=load"; 
  //was var UrlToPass = 'action=load'; 
  gridder.html('loading..');       
  $.ajax({ 
     url : 'cartajax.php', 
     contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-7', 
     type : 'POST', 
     data : UrlToPass, 
     success: function(responseText) { 
        gridder.html(responseText); 
     } 
  });
```

}

and in ajax.php i have this code :

```
enter code here $action = $_POST['action'];  switch($action) { case "load":
```

and i cant see anything but only loading...
the problem is only in ie8

Comment: Did you find any error in console ? Also check `jQuery` version and its support for `IE8`

Comment: What's with the `;charset=ISO-8859-7` ?

Comment: Musa its greek encoding

Comment: Rayon no i dont take any console error

Answer (score 0):

`IE8` has problems inserting long strings of text with `jQuery's html()`

Probably this is a known bug. You can refer [this](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12871)

A way around is

```
try {
    //new browsers
    $('#domElement').html(responseText);
} catch (e) {
    //IE8
    $('#domElement').innerHTML = responseText;
}
```

**EDIT-1**

```
function LoadGrid() { 
 // var gridder = $('#as_gridder'); 
  var UrlToPass = "action=load"; 
  //was var UrlToPass = 'action=load'; 
  gridder.html('loading..');       
  $.ajax({ 
     url : 'cartajax.php', 
     contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-7', 
     type : 'POST', 
     data : UrlToPass, 
     success: function(responseText) { 
        try{
            $('#as_gridder').html(responseText);
        } catch (e) {
            //IE8
            $('#as_gridder').innerHTML = responseText;
        }
     } 
  }); 
}
```